# How to install WinUSB .INF file on Windows Phone 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, winusb

My Windows Phone 10 mobile device can operate the USB in OTG mode and I can plug in USB Flash memory for example.    I would like to connect my custom device into the Windows Phone and use it from a Windows Store App on the phone.  In theory, I could install a .INF file that defines the WinUSB interface for my device.

How to install a .INF file on a Win 10 phone that enables WinUSB access to my device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for independent developers to install a .INF file on a Windows 10 mobile device to define the WinUSB interface.   Only the mobile OEM can place device drivers or device .INF files into the mobile device image at the time the image is created.

As an alternative if the USB device firmware can be changed, program it use the [Microsoft Extended Feature Descriptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh450799) to appear as a WinUSB device.

Comment: Does this apply for all device drivers? Can you perform kernel mode debugging on windows phone? There is an option in visual studio 2015 which lets you select a "mobile" device.

Comment: This does apply to all device drivers - there's no way to release a new device for Windows 10 Mobile along with a custom driver.   Third party devices could be used if they can appear as a WinUSB device.